# MERN file download from blob in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have an app where a user clicks a link and is shown a copy of an image from my server. My server is returning me the blob. I want to give my user the ability to click a button on this page and download the file from the link. This link may contain a jpeg or even a csv file. I tried using js-file-downloader but no luck

Here is my react component below

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Col, Button } from 'reactstrap'
import { fileDownload } from 'js-file-download';

const PreviewMedia = ({match}) => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState()
    const [image, setImage] = useState()

    console.log('image', image)
const handleClick = () => {
    window.open(image) <--- this handleClick should be downloading the image state which is a blob
}
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        axios({
        url:`http://localhost:5000/media/${match.params.imageID}`, // <----------first get request
        method:"GET"
      }).then(res =>  setFile(res.data))
 } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)        
    } }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("this ran")
        if(!file) {
        } else {
        axios({
            url: file?.links?.content_direct_temporary, //<----------------returns the blob second get request once done
            method:"GET"
          }).then(res => { 
            setImage(res.data) // <--- res.data is a blob
        
            })}
    }, [file])

console.log("PREVIEW MEDIA-----------file", file)


  return (
    <div>
        <Col className="text-center">
            {image && <img src={image} ></img>} //<--successfully renders image or nothing if file which is fine
        </Col>
        <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center" >
        <Button color="primary" onClick={handleClick} className=" my-3 text-white">
                Download file 
        </Button>
        </Col>
    </div>
  )


}

export default PreviewMedia
```

Answer (score 1):

super simple. no need for external library for this. THIS ONLY WORKS FOR SAME ORIGIN URLS THOUGH BUT SERVES MY CASE

```
<div>
        <Col className="text-center">
            {image && <img src={image} ></img>} //<--successfully renders image or nothing if file which is fine
        </Col>
        <Col className="d-flex justify-content-center" >
<a href={image} download > // wrap this anchor tag around button w/ download attribute
        <Button color="primary" onClick={handleClick} className=" my-3 text-white">
                Download file 
        </Button>
         </a>
        </Col>
    </div>
<a download="custom-filename.jpg" href="/path/to/image" title="ImageName">
    
</a>
```